# How to make an animated sprite look like it's walking forward in Flame Game?

Tags: flutter, flame

I've got a moving sprite that animates over a loop of 4 images to make it look like it's walking in one spot.  I want to make the sprite move forward by a certain amount when I click a button.  I've tried looking for how this might be done, but it's just made me confused.  I've found this information sheet by Flame Game that explain effects, but I don't understand how to apply it to what I've got (https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/effects.html).

This is the constructor for the class that makes the dog move:

```
  Dog()
      : super(
    priority: 1,
    playing: true,
    scale: Vector2(1, 1),
    size: Vector2.all(50),
  ) {
    animation = SpriteAnimation.spriteList(runPictures, stepTime: 0.2);
    position = Vector2(150.0, 150.0);
  }
```

I want the dog to move 100 pixels towards the top of the screen, while it's going through the loop above, when a button is clicked.  This button would send it to a class that would make it move.  If someone could provide sample code or a useful tutorial, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you want to add a `MoveByEffect` to the component.

I assume that you already have the button set up and that you have access to an instance of the `Dog` component from there, then you simply add the effect to the component:

```dart
final dog = Dog(...);

// Or whatever callback you have for the button
void onTap() {
  dog.add(
    MoveByEffect(Vector2(0, -100), EffectController(duration: 1)),
  );  
}
```

This will move the dog 100px upwards during one second.